# ¿Qué término se usa en español para "Game Changer"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

¿Qué término se usa (o podemos usar) en español para "Game Changer"?

"**Game Changer**" o "**game changing**" [se define](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/game_changer) como:

> (literally or figuratively) Something unexpected which **changes the rules of a process** viewed as a game.
>
> (sports or figuratively) Critical and having the potential to alter the overall outcome. <sub>([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/game-changing))</sub>
>
> It refers to something that happens to change the expected outcome of the game.<sub>[(Wordreference)](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/game-changer.2328913/)</sub>

Puede incluso referirse a una persona:

> 1. A person who is a visionary. 2. A company that alters its business strategy and conceives an entirely new business plan. <sub>([(Investopedia)](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/game-changer.asp))</sub>

Un *game changer* es algo que "cambia las reglas (y el resultado) del juego". Es decir, que altera el dominio o industria de tal manera que las cosas no vuelven a ser lo mismo, y casi se adaptan a este efecto o entidad *game changer*. Por ejemplo:

> La película "El Caballero Oscuro" de Christopher Nolan fue un *game changer*. Casi todas las pelis de superhéroes que se ha nhecho despues de esta son más adultas y oscuras.
>
> El [modelo empresarial de Spotify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mpsn3WaI_4k) fue un completo *game changer*. Muchas empresas establecidas y *start ups* han copiado el modelo, y hasta se le conoce como "el modelo de Spotify".
>
> When Apple introduced the iPod, the product was a *game changer*. It revolutionized the way in which music was purchased and consumed. Though other companies had already launched MP3 players, Apple's product had a more attractive design, a big marketing budget, and, most important, a music platform (iTunes) that virtually dictated how music would be distributed going forward. <sub>([investinganswers](http://www.investinganswers.com/financial-dictionary/businesses-corporations/game-changer-6671))</sub>

Este último ejemplo, por cierto,  añade a la definión:

> Game changers are **disruptive**. They are sometimes crazy ideas. [...] **A game changer is a person or thing that radically changes an industry or a company**.

Comment: El término que me suena más cerca a estos sería "punta de lanza", refiriéndose a la gente que innova o va adelante.

Comment: No sé si "visionario" podría aplicar aquí.

Comment: El traductor de Google propone (entre otros) "elemento de cambio" que no me parece mal...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo puedes generar una respuesta :)

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene un voto negativo. Se anima alguie a explicar por qué razón esta pregunta no es clara o útil o no genera valor para la comunidad? A fin de cuentas, el paradigma de los _stacks_ es que son moderados por la comunidad y nosotros decidimos [dónde queremos que vaya esto](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/cumplimos-5-a%c3%b1os-en-beta).

Comment: @walen, ese es precisamente el motivo de la pregunta. Uno de los motivos es intentar encontrar una versión española de ese anglicismo (la RAE dice que [usamos demasiados](http://www.eltiempo.com/estilo-de-vida/educacion/campana-rae-contra-anglicismos/16597605)) y encontrar un término que resuma esa expresión larga. Otro, es ayudar a mantener esta comunidad generando valor y contenido. "Cambiar las reglas del juego" es por supuesto una respuesta válida (es la mejor??), y podría tener su propia entrada para poder votarla y compararla con otras propuestas de otros usuarios (todo genera valor).

Comment: Estaría bien que la gente que vota negativo dijera por qué lo hace, en algunas preguntas puede estar más o menos claro el motivo pero en otras no tanto. También añado que desde móvil es fácil votar al revés de lo que quieres (las flechas están muy juntas) o incluso votar sin querer, a mi me ha pasado haciendo scroll darle a la flecha por error.

Comment: @blonfu Además creo que es especialmente importante en las contribuciones (preguntas o respuestas) de nuevos usuarios. A veces los recién llegados no conocen todas las posibilidades (funcionalidad) de la plataforma (en parte porque no tienen reputación suficiente para ciertos privilegios), o no saben dar formato o simplemente tienen un estilo diferente al que ya damos por aceptado aqui y se les castiga con negativos, asumiendo que es por falta de interés o dejadez, en lugar de falta de experiencia. Poca gente se molesta en "educarles" en buenas prácticas, para que estén más cómodos y se queden

Answer (score 13):

Es español solemos usar la expresión *marcar un antes y un después* con un significado similar. En los ejemplos que mencionas:

> La película "El Caballero Oscuro" de Christopher Nolan marcó un antes y un
> después en las pelis de superhéroes. Casi todas las que se han hecho
> despues de esta son más adultas y oscuras.
>
> El modelo empresarial de Spotify marcó un antes y un después. Muchas
> empresas establecidas y start ups han copiado el modelo, y hasta se le
> conoce como "el modelo de Spotify".
>
> Cuando Apple introdujo el iPod, marcó un antes y un después. Revolucionó
> la forma de comprar y consumir música [...]

Answer (score 10):

Además de lo que propone @Gorpik, que me parece perfecto, se me ocurre la palabra *revolucionar* que, por cierto, aparece en la frase de ejemplo de los iPod. Siguiendo con los mismos ejemplos:

> La película "El Caballero Oscuro" de Christopher Nolan revolucionó las películas de superhéroes. Casi todas las que se han hecho despues de esta son más adultas y oscuras.
>
> El modelo empresarial de Spotify revolucionó la industria. Muchas empresas establecidas y start ups han copiado el modelo, y hasta se le conoce como "el modelo de Spotify".

También *punto de inflexión* aunque se suele utilizar más para cambios personales que globales. Y otra podría ser *cambio de paradigma*.

Comment: _Punto de inflexión_ me gusta y se usa mucho.

Comment: Muy buenas aportaciones. Como con "innovador" creo que "revolucionario" no recoge todas las caracteristicas del "game changer", pero "punto de inflexion" y "cambio de paradigma" son muy buenas.

Comment: Entré a ver las respuestas con Punto de inflexión en mente. Me parece que es muy buena opción y no veo cómo pueda estar limitado a cambios personales.

Comment: @daniloquio no digo que esté limitado a ese contexto pero tengo la sensación de haberlo leído/oído normalmente para definir un momento en la vida de una persona, quizá solo sea una apreciación mía.

Answer (score 9):

Una que acabo de leer en un artículo por Internet: "[redefinir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VYC4y16)":

> La culminación de la saga que **redefinió** el género de las aventuras [...].

Ejemplos:

> La película "El Caballero Oscuro" de Christopher Nolan **redefinió** las pelis de superhéroes.
>
> Spotify **redefinió** los modelos empresariales.
>
> Cuando Apple introdujo el iPod, **redefinió** la forma de comprar y consumir música [...]

Comment: +1. Simple y elegante y captura bastantes de las connotaciones de "game changer". Aparte, al ser un único término se le puede usar un poco más como el término anglófono.

Comment: Muy buena, me gusta esa también. Lo que me parece mas difícil es encontrar alguna que sirva para referirse a una persona como parece que ocurre en inglés según cuenta Diego.

Comment: @blonfu sí, sé que "redefinir" es un verbo y "game changer" sería más bien un adjetivo aplicado al elemento de cambio (o un sustantivo, según se use). Sin embargo, para traducir basta con poner dicho elemento de cambio como sujeto de la oración (que usa el verbo "redefinir"), en vez de como sustantivo al que aplica "game changer". Recordemos que una buena traducción no debe ser literal, simplemente debe hacer que la imagen mental formada por los hablantes de ambos idiomas sea la misma.

Answer (score 5):

Otra opción que oigo en España sería **rompedor**.

[Rompedor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WeuEFWm)

> 2. adj. Muy avanzado e innovador. Teoría rompedora.

Answer (score 4):

En México también suele usarse el término **parteaguas**:

> Momento, personaje o suceso de trascendencia tal que aparenta dividir
>   o separar lo previo de lo consecuente.
>   [Parteaguas](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/parteaguas)

Por ejemplo:

> La película "El Caballero Oscuro" de Christopher Nolan **fue un
>   parteaguas** en las pelis de superhéroes. Casi todas las que se han
>   hecho despues de esta son más adultas y oscuras.
>
> El modelo empresarial de Spotify **fue un parteaguas**. Muchas
>   empresas establecidas y start ups han copiado el modelo, y hasta se le
>   conoce como "el modelo de Spotify".
>
> Cuando Apple introdujo el iPod, **significó un parteaguas**. Revolucionó la
>   forma de comprar y consumir música [...]

Comment: El significado parece que cuadra pero ¿dónde se usa? En España no creo, al menos jamás he oído esa palabra. En varios diccionarios que he mirado no aparece aunque si he encontrado varias referencias a la palabra con ese significado

Comment: @blonfu en **méxico** se usa basante, desconozco la difusión en otros paises latinos

Comment: Buscando en el CREA más del 90% de las coincidencias son de México, supongo que sobre todo se usa allí. Es una buena traducción para los sitios donde se entienda.

Answer (score 4):

Existe un término equivalente en español que se usa frecuentemente para describir este concepto en particular. Sin embargo, el término en cuestión no es un sustantivo, por lo que requiere que la frase se modifique para utilizarlo.

"**Game Changing**" es "**cambiar las reglas del juego**", un "**game changer**" es *un agente que causa que cambien las reglas del juego*.

Aquí hay algunos ejemplos de su uso:

- ["Triunfo de Trump *cambia las reglas del juego*".](http://eleconomista.com.mx/mercados-estadisticas/2016/11/13/triunfo-trump-cambia-las-reglas-juego) (Usado en México)
- ["Empresarios advierten que la reforma en ganancias “*cambia las reglas de juego* y desalienta la inversión.”"](http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201612/172899-advirten-que-la-reforma-en-ganancias-cambia-las-reglas-de-juego-y-desalienta-la-inversion.html) (Usado en Argentina)
- "[Estamos en un momento crítico donde solo el que tenga de meta *cambiar las reglas del juego* se destacará y crecerá.](http://elvocero.com/clave-para-el-2016-cambiar-las-reglas-del-juego/)"  (Usado en Puerto Rico)
- ["*Cambia las reglas del juego* y conduce tu negocio al éxito en 1, 2, 3… ¡Ya!"](http://blog.auraportal.com/es/proximo-evento-cambia-las-reglas-del-juego-vienes/) (Usado en España)

Como se puede observar, "*x* **cambia las reglas del juego**" es una forma general de denominar a un "**game changer**".

Así bien, los ejemplos anteriores muestran que la frase no es regional y se usa para referirse a cambios que sean tanto positivos como negativos.

Los ejemplos presentados en la pregunta necesitan adaptarse un poco para utilizar la frase:

> La película "El Caballero Oscuro" de Christopher Nolan **cambió las reglas del juego**. Casi todas las pelis de superhéroes que se han hecho despues de esta son más adultas y oscuras.
>
> El modelo empresarial de Spotify **cambió *completamente* las reglas del juego**. Muchas empresas establecidas y start ups han copiado el modelo, y hasta se le conoce como "el modelo de Spotify".
>
> Cuando Apple introdujo el iPod, el producto **cambió las reglas del juego**. Revolucionó la manera en la que la música se compra y consume. [*...*]

Sin embargo, tras realizar esos pequeños cambios suenan más naturales. Nótese que como la frase es un verbo se puede utilizar en diferentes tiempos como pasado (***cambió*** las reglas del juego), presente (***cambia*** las reglas del juego) y futuro (***cambiará*** las reglas del juego).

Comment: Gracias Jorge, gran respuesta. +1, pero posiblemente también candidata a mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

El equivalente de un **gamer changer** en español sería un **innovador**.

**[Innovar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LgzBfa6)**:

> 1. tr. Mudar o alterar algo, ***introduciendo novedades.***

En el caso de innovar, la persona que innova/renueva *cambia parcial o por completo las normas establecidas* e incluso, *genera nuevas formas* de crear las cosas.

Comment: No es mala respuesta (+1), pero no estoy completamente de acuerdo. La persona que innova no siempre cambia las normas. A veces solo aporta algo nuevo, algo más. Alguien puede introducir un ["innovador sistema de limpieza pirolítica para hornos](http://innovacionparatuvida.bosch-home.es/como-funciona-un-horno-pirolitico/) pero eso no significa que todos los hornos empiecen a copiar y usar el sistema. Asi que creo que "innovar" no recoge realmente las connotaciones del cambio radical en la industria (que a veces es obligado para seguir en el negocio) del _game changer_.

Answer (score -1):

Personalmente creo que una buena analogía para llevar este concepto de "game changer" al español sería "efecto bisagra". Esto nos lleva a pensar que estamos hablando de lo mismo pero se abre una nueva dimensión que antes no se conocía. Espero les sirva.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio, Renzo! Te agradecemos tu respuesta, pero aquí nos gustan las respuestas amplias, documentadas y con cuantos más datos mejor. Yo no conozco el término "efecto bisagra", ¿podrías explicarlo un poco más y aportarnos citas de textos publicados donde se use con el sentido de "game changer"? Danos más información y votaremos positivamente y con gusto tu respuesta. ¡Anímate!

Comment: Buscando "efecto bisagra" en google encuentro algunos enlaces. Aparentemente no está para nada relacionado con "game changer". Tiene más el sentido como de "darle la vuelta 180 grados". En [uno de los artículos](https://blogs.elcomercio.es/retorcida-realidad/2013/11/06/el-efecto-bisagra/) tiene el sentido de "algo que se vuelve contra ti". En [otro](https://laeconomiasocial.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/el-efecto-bisagra/) es "darle la vuelta a la tortilla". El efecto de ambos podría cambiar el juego, pero la expresión no tiene las mismas connotaciones que "game changer".