# Cómo traducir al español "BHAG"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, solicitud-de-término

Un "BHAG"o "[Big Hairy Audacious Goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Hairy_Audacious_Goal)" es

> a **strategic business statement** similar to a vision statement which is created to focus an organization on a single medium-long term organization-wide goal which is *audacious*, likely to be externally questionable, but not internally regarded as *impossible*.

Es decir, que es un objetivo empresarial a largo plazo. Es *grande*, *audaz* y "*peludo*". Lo de grande se entiende porque el objetivo es muy ambicioso, aunque  sea a largo plazo. Es audaz por el valor que aporta a la empresa o entidad (aunque sin ánimo de ser necesariamente un *[game changer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19109/5481)*).

Lo que cuesta traducir es lo de "peludo", que lo veo como si fuera uno de esos monstruos grandes y peludos que dan miedo. Otra posibilidad es traducir como "[peliagudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SNxntVg)"

> adj. coloq. Dicho de un negocio o de otra cosa: Difícil de resolver o entender.

Es decir, en ambos caso, dificil, que da miedo o respeto, pero no imposible de superar.

Es por tanto "Gran Objetivo Audaz y Peliagudo" la traducción más apropiada para "Big Hairy Audacious Goal"? Hay alguna traducción aceptada o usada como la tradución "de facto"? Se le ocurre a alguien una mejor?

Comment: No conocía el término, así que no sé si existe algo parecido en español. ¿Es necesario que _peludo_ se incluya en la traducción? Sinceramente, lo veo más como una palabra para enfatizar "por exageración", que algo que requiera ser traducido estrictamente, sobre todo si no es una frase que se utilice rara vez, sino un término propio de uso común. Yo lo omitiría y dejaría simplemente "Gran y Audaz Objetivo", "Gran Objetivo Audaz" u "Objetivo Grande y Audaz" (personalmente, este último es el que mejor me suena, es el menos rebuscado, sobre todo, de nuevo, para un término propio de uso común).

Comment: I think the meaning of hairy intended here is more like your suggestion of _que dan miedo_ and does not have a lot to do with hair. The translation you give for _peliagudo_ does not quite have the right ring to me.

Comment: @mdewey Great! thank you for that valuable insight! So, there is even more need to find a proper way to find a suitable translation for "hairy" in this context, with the connotations of "scary, challenging, daring, etc."

Comment: @nox, Tu comentario es una respuesta válida. "FAQ" para mi puede ser prefectametne "preguntas frecuentes". No soy tan purista para exigir que deba ser traducido como "Preguntas **más** frecuentes". Traducir no es una ciencia exacta y depende de muchas cosas. Por eso planteé la pregunta. Estoy seguro de que entre todos se nos pueden ocurrir cosas que a mi solo no se me ocurrirían, y se que aqui hay gente que hace aportaciones de gran valor. difrentes usuario propondrán cada uno su propio enfoque y podemos comparar y valorar. No hay respuesta errónea tampoco.

Comment: la respuesta de @Nox suena bien....pero ¿porqué no adicionarle también lo peludo?.  Nosotros también usamos "peludo" para una cosa difícil. Entonces "Objetivo Grande Audaz y Peludo OGAP" sería mi propuesta.

Comment: @DGaleano, mi idea al lanzar la pregunta era fomentar la participación y la discusión, aunque más en forma de respuestas que de comentarios. Creo que tienes razón, y sigo repitiendo que todos esos comentarios son respuesta válidas que mediante el modelo de este _stack_ las votamos para respladar. Y seguro que alguien propone alguna alternativa intersante e ingeniosa para "hairy" u otros componentes del acrónimo.

Comment: El modelo del _stack_ permite respuestas y comentarios. Las respuestas pretenden responder a la pregunta (y acumular votos lo que para algunos es muy importante y le da sentido a su participación, lo que para mi es irrelevante) y los comentarios pretenden fomentar la discusión, aportar elementos de juicio, complementar otras respuestas, aclarar conceptos y en general hacer todo tipo de aportes menores. Como considero que lo escrito antes por mi no merece el título de respuesta, lo dejo como comentario esperando que para alguien sea de alguna utilidad.

Comment: No conocía esas siglas. He buscado un poco por ahí y aparece traducido así en bastantes sitios: Grandioso Descabellado Audaz Objetivo. A mi me gusta mas *peliagudo* como propones que *descabellado* y prefiero *meta* que *objetivo* en este caso. Mi propuesta: Gran Meta Peliaguda y Audaz

Comment: @DGaleano, sería interesante ver lo que pasaba por aquí si no hubiese puntos ni medallas (hay mucha gente que piensa que el sistema de SO es un lastre para la propia web), pero si esto solo tuviese comentarios sería como cualquier otro foro. Incluso los comentarios pueden ser votados y creo que el poder votar las respuesta ayuda  a respaldarlas. También ayuda al que llega para consultarlas, porque en lugar de tener que leer todo el contenido lo tiene organizado y validado por la comunidad. Ahora, en lo que motiva o como quiere participar cada uno ya no me meto.

Comment: Muy interesante lo comentado por @DGaleano y Diego por aquí, no lo había visto hasta ahora :) Creo que todos los aquí presentes hemos acumulado suficiente reputación por aquí para poder utilizar todas las herramientas que la comunidad nos proporciona a partir de cierto punto. De ahí que entiendo esa no necesidad de responder y la poca relevancia de la reputación (de hecho, últimamente incluso los _bounties_ quedan desiertos, entiendo que su motivación decayó). Ahora bien, yo en general abogo por sí añadir una respuesta pues permite una mejor discusión con sus respectivos comentarios.

Answer (score 3):

La traducción en Español sería "*Meta Grande, Peluda y Audaz*", también se maneja "*Meta Grande y Audaz*" (MEGA) y la variante "*Meta Grande, Espeluznante y Audaz*".

He aquí algunos ejemplos donde se utiliza actualmente "*Meta Grande, Peluda y Audaz*":

- [Comunicando la Sustentabilidad: Cómo producir campañas públicas efectivas](https://books.google.com/books?id=kHw_5Nv2WfMC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=Meta%20Grande,%20Peluda%20y%20Audaz&source=bl&ots=2ojhxDMevK&sig=hRWKwDpWeF7-6hGfKWKhVlKsfMI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPyZfkvavRAhUJSyYKHaa9CEUQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=Meta%20Grande%2C%20Peluda%20y%20Audaz&f=false), en el 2005
- [Creando negocios rentables en Internet](http://www.creandonegocios.com/meta-bhag/), en el 2012
- [Meca Tecnología](http://meca-tecnologia.blogspot.com/2015/05/bhag-una-meta-grande-peluda-y-audaz.html), en el 2015

Aquí otros dónde se emplea "*Meta Grande y Audaz*" (MEGA):

- [Las Metas Grandes y Audaces](http://advisors.com.co/blog/las-metas-grandes-y-audaces/), en el 2008
- [Las Metas Grandes](https://prezi.com/jvva6gzupeaf/las-metas-grandes/) (Presentación), en el 2013
- [La Policía Nacional (de Colombia) acoge como Meta Grande y Audaz](https://www.policia.gov.co/mision-vision-mega-principios-valores-funciones), en el 2017

Y finalmente otros para "*Meta Grande, Espeluznante y Audaz*":

- [!Vive tu sueño!](https://books.google.com/books?id=HFx7Fq4rsa0C&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=meta%20grande%20audaz%20espeluznante&source=bl&ots=NEa2dUQ80a&sig=-tP-tTyn5MDN9P2jKVyfeGC1x2g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGrYeK66vRAhXD6iYKHW09B1AQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=meta%20grande%20audaz%20espeluznante&f=false) (Libro), en el 2009
- [Manifestando la vida de tus sueños con ETF](http://aheft.com/index.php/comunidad/2012-03-07-12-16-47/general/inspiracion/8815-manifesting-sp), en el 2012
- [¿Conoce el rumbo de su organización?](http://technologicalmanagementfundamentals.blogspot.com/2015/05/conoce-el-rumbo-de-su-organizacion.html), en el 2015

Cabe señalar que aunque es tentador considerar "*Meta Grande y Audaz*" como un concepto diferente de "*Meta Grande, Peluda y Audaz*", [ambos](http://www.creandonegocios.com/meta-bhag/) son [atribuidos a Collins y Porras](http://advisors.com.co/blog/las-metas-grandes-y-audaces/) (Es decir, son sinónimos del mismo concepto). También es importante notar que tanto el vínculo que define "*Metas Grandes y Audaces*" (en lugar de "*Meta Grande, Peluda y Audaz*") y uno de sus usos representativos (La Policía Nacional) son Colombianos.

En cuanto al uso de "*Meta Grande, Espeluznante y Audaz*", cuenta con sus variaciones (tal como "*Gran Meta Espeluznante y Audaz*") pero se podría adaptar a "*Meta Espeluznante, Grande y Audaz*" y así mantener el acrónimo de "*MEGA*".

Comment: Interesante. Me gusta poder usar MEGA como acrónimo (como BHAG). Sigo prefiriendo "peliagudo" a "peludo", pero tampoco quiero ser un "purista" de la traducción, ya que parece ser que dejar "hairy" fuera de la traducción puede dar lugar a aoluciones más interesantes.

Comment: @Diego A mí también me parece "*peliagudo*" más apropiado que "*peludo*", sin embargo, considero que "*espeluznante*" sería incluso una mejor manera de expresar lo que se busca dar a entender. Ahora que lo pienso, déjame ver si se usa el término "*espeluznante*"...

Comment: @Diego Listo, agregué más a mi respuesta tras una breve investigación. También busqué para ver si el término "*Meta Grande, Peliaguda y Audaz*" es usado pero no encontré resultado alguno.

Comment: "Espeluznante" es mucho mejor que "peliagudo", en mi opinión, y mucho mejor que "peludo".  Muy buena ocurrencia.

Comment: @Diego Gracias, Diego.

Answer (score 2):

Existe un concepto parecido que se usa en español de negocios, el cual tiene dos variaciones:

- Disparar a la luna
- Tirar piedras a la luna

El término "*Disparar a la luna*" viene del libro ["Dispara a la luna" de Reyes Calderón](http://www.elmundo.es/comunidad-valenciana/2016/03/03/56d88e6cca4741a9588b457d.html). La autora, a su vez, utiliza una traducción de "*Shoot for the moon*" que es un término en inglés para aspirar a ser mejor (pensar en grande). Es probable que el término origine de [un cuento de Alejandro Jodorowsky](https://innovacion.wordpress.com/2007/03/30/disparando-a-la-luna/), en la que un arquero "*caza a la luna*" y aunque nunca logra llevar a cabo tal meta se torna en el mejor arquero del mundo.

El término "*tirar piedras a la luna*" es [una variante del cuento de Alejandro Jodorowsky](http://www.teregalomialegria.com/2013/10/piensa-en-grande-el-lanzador-de-piedras-a-la-luna/), con un pastor que todas las noches arrojaba piedras a la luna y que se torna en el mejor lanzador de piedras de la comarca. [El sentido es el mismo](http://elpais.com/diario/2003/11/27/cvalenciana/1069964301_850215.html), pero la variación es clara.

La mayor diferencia con "*BHAG*" es que la meta es imposible de alcanzar, pero el espíritu detrás de un objetivo *grande*, *audaz* y *peliagudo* se mantiene.

Comment: Esta respuesta es buena (+1), pero como dices "disparar a la luna" es la traducción de "moonshot", un término parecido a BHAG, pero no necesariamente con las mismas connotaciones.

Comment: @Diego Tienes razón, encontré otra opción que presentaré como una respuesta adicional ya que es absolutamente distinta a la que presenté.

Answer (score 1):

Objetivo alto, grande, lejano e inalcanzable.

Pero creo que lo de inalcanzable no lo vas a querer decir ya que lo que quieres es que se cumpla y se vea posible.

Comment: Gracias por la propuesta, pero la verdad es que lo de "alto" no me convence. Tampoco "lejano", aunque un objetivo de este tipo desde luego no se alcanza a corto plazo.Por último, tampoco parece mantener las connotaciones de "Hairy" y "audacious".

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo lo que dice en inglés Wikipedia propondría traducirlo como una "Meta grande y ambiciosa".
Como sucede muchas veces con esas frases y expresiones que se inventan en inglés, es que desconocemos el contexto (autor, año, etc) en el cual se inventan o crean esas frases.